# Rails, Gruff and image quality

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using gruff in my rails application along with Prawn PDF to insert a graph into a downloadable PDF. But i'm having some issues with the quality of the graph its displaying. Does anyone know how this can be rectified? It's only at 360 px wide.

[Image Here for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVS1Q.png)

Prawn Code

```
 name = @result.each do |v| v.variety.variety_name end
    lint = @result.map {|v| v.lint/227 } 
  g = Gruff::Bar.new(360)
  g.data(:lint, lint, '#00463f')
  @results.each do |item|
  g.title = "#{item.site.site_name} Variety Summary Graph"
  g.title_font_size = 24
  end
  g.labels = {}
  @result.each_with_index do |v, i|
  g.labels[i] = v.variety.variety_name
  g.y_axis_label = 'Yield (bales/ha)'
  g.marker_font_size = 24
  g.marker_count = 5
  g.theme = {:marker_color => '#000000', :font_color => '#000000', :background_colors => %w(#ffffff #ffffff)}
  g.minimum_value = 0
  g.hide_legend = true
  end

  g.write("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/chart/chart.png")

  image "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/chart/chart.png"
```

Comment: Hi, you seem new here. It's much easier for us to help you if you provide the code that you are actually using. We can then look at the code and find any errors.

Comment: Thanks Taryn, I have added the prawn/gruff code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thou art suffering from a similar affliction to mine own. For mine is only 400 pixels wide, but low and behold, for the answer may be within thy code!

```
  g = Gruff::Bar.new(360)
```

For, where there is 360, cannot there not be 800?

g = Gruff::Bar.new(800)

Now, all thou must do is order thy prawn to scale thine image.

```
image "graph.png", :scale => 0.68
```

To understand thy prawn further, please read this page: [Module: Prawn::Images](http://prawnpdf.org/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Images.html)